# Separate java projects with jacoco code coverage reports are generated separately using maven. Consolidated report generated is blank

Tags: java, html, merge, report, jacoco-maven-plugin

Having separate java projects (non-multi module projects) with jacoco code coverage reports are generated separately using maven. Each one having its own target\jacoco.exec coverage file and Html reports; so having number of those. I am trying to consolidate all of those into one and generate one jacoco.exec and one html report.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.9</version>...


            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>merge-reports</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>merge</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <fileSets>
                            <fileSet>
                                <directory>lambda/face-email-handler/target/</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>*.exec</include>
                                </includes>
                            </fileSet>
                            <!-- Repeat for other projects -->
                        </fileSets>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report-aggregate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <dataFileIncludes>
                            <dataFileInclude>target/jacoco.exec</dataFileInclude>
                        </dataFileIncludes>
                        <includes>
                            <include>edu/uca/**</include>
                        </includes>
                        <outputDirectory>target/site/jacoco-coverage-aggregate</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>...
```

So able to have one jacoco.exec but html report being generated is blank. Specific direction is appreciated.
[image: Blank html consolidated code coverage report]

Answer (score 0):

For the second part use $ java -jar jacococli.jar report ....it generates the html report